# How to fix the invalid identifier of bash?

Tags: bash, terminal

When I open terminal, I get following error at the top.

```
bash: export: `/usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin': not a valid identifier
```

[image: Snapshot of error]

I am new to linux and I was trying to execute ls command but it was not working and giving some error so I followed this answer to fix it. Now I am able to list down the file using ls command but getting this error. I wonder it will have some serious affect somewhere else or not.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my path in `~/.bashrc` was not correct. So this is what I did.

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

After the in the opened file I update the PATH to this at the end of the file.

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
```